# Nodejs - differentiating unique devices statelessly

Tags: node.js, http, ip-address

Нello! Let's say we're trying to differentiate unique devices that contact our node http server:

```
require('http').createServer((req, res) => {

  let uniqueDeviceId = getUniqueDeviceId(req);
  res.end(`Our unique id for you is "${uniqueDeviceId}"!`);

}).listen(80, '<my public ip>', 511);
```

I am toying with this implementation of `getUniqueDeviceId`:

```
let getUniqueDeviceId = ({ connection }) => `${connection.remoteAddress}:${connection.remotePort}`;
```

I understand that HTTP architecture is *designed to prevent identification of specific devices without consent*. I know that to identify a device properly, a login mechanism must be used. I therefore know that my `getUniqueDeviceId` implementation must have downsides and failure cases (but I don't know what they are).

**Under what conditions will this implementation fail?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the world full of IPv4 addresses it will fail due to the fact, that public IP addresses are shared among local networks. Check out how Network Address Translation [(NAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) works. For example, if you have a WiFi router in your home and you have some amount of devices, which are connected to the internet through this router, they will have the same public IP. Partially this is done in order to reduce IPv4 addresses consumption. There are only 4,294,967,296 of them, back in the days people couldn't even think that the world will have such a big amount of devices in public internet. That's we're slowly moving towards IPv6, capacity of which is **much** bigger.

In your particular situation, different devices from the same IP addresses will look the same to your app. Also if device A switches from network N to network M, your app will not figure out that it's the same device A, since it's going to have different public IP.

Also, keep in mind that remote ports are random from 0 to 65535, when clients are connecting to your web server. The port on which the server is listening is static, but the port through which the client will establish a connection with you, is only established during connection initialization with help of underlying OS.

Comment: I believe that a NAT router keeps a unique port for each device, even if they all use the same IP. This is why I'm using both `req.connection.remoteAddress` *and* `req.connection.remotePort` - the port should differentiate devices under the same NAT router, shouldn't it? That's a great point about a device which changes its default gateway!

Comment: You are right it does keep unique port per device, but I wouldn't rely on that. Consider a case when NAT is rebooted, which is a common thing to do when you lose internet at home, or maybe when you bought a new router, or anything else similar.

Comment: Ah, another thing I didn't think of! So it sounds like a device's identity becomes unknowable, with my method, when its default gateway's NAT assignment changes (whether it's the default gateway itself, or just its mapping, which is undergoing change).

Comment: Yup, sounds so. If your clients are not browsers or mobile apps, it becomes harder to track them. You could use cookies or similar techniques.